# Rails - Can't monkey-patch wicked_pdf gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

I am trying to monkey-patch the [wicked_pdf gem](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf), but my patch is not being recognized.

If I go into the source code in my local copy of the gem and modify the [#print_command method](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/8f970f29c4de4f737815446549895a5a9f234c95/lib/wicked_pdf.rb#L109) of the WickedPdf class, my modification is reflected in the logs when I view a pdf.

```
# local/gem/path/lib/wicked_pdf.rb
def print_command(cmd)
  puts "\n\nthis is my modification\n\n" # appears in logs
end
```

However, when I try to implement the same idea as a monkey-patch, in an initializer let's say, that modification is not reflected.

```
# config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb
module WickedPdfExtension
  def print_command(cmd)
    puts "\n\nthis is my modification\n\n" # does not appear in logs
  end
end

WickedPdf.include(WickedPdfExtension)
```

I've check that the `WickedPdf` class exists at the time that I am extending it, and I've confirmed that this happens with other methods, public and private, in the `WickedPdf` class. Why is my monkey-patch ineffective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WickedPdf#print_command` is directly defined in the class `WickedPdf` (see [the source code](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/master/lib/wicked_pdf.rb#L109)), so it shadows any `#print_command` defined in the modules `include`d by the class. To override it's behavior, you can use `Module#prepend` if you are using Ruby >= 2.0.0, or alias method chain otherwise. Of course you can always open the class `WickedPdf` and redefine the method no matter which version of Ruby you are using.

### Using `Module#prepend`

```
module WickedPdfExtension
  def print_command(cmd)
    puts "\n\nthis is my modification\n\n"
  end
end

WickedPdf.prepend(WickedPdfExtension)
```

### Using alias method chain

```
module WickedPdfExtension
  extends ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def print_command_with_modification(cmd)
      puts "\n\nthis is my modification\n\n"
    end

    alias_method_chain :print_command, :modification
  end
end

WickedPdf.include(WickedPdfExtension)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to *open* the class:

```
class WickedPdf
  def print_command(cmd)
    puts "\n\nthis is my modification\n\n" 
  end
end
```